# How to calculate number of subdirectories and byte count per file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, find, wc

Can I get help fixing my code to count every subdirectory (excluding "PATH" itself)?

```
num_directories=$( find $dir -type d | wc -l)
```

Also need help fixing the total byte count of each file

```
total_size=$( find $dir -type f -ls | awk '{total+=5}END{print total}';)
```

I understand you won't have access to the same files but I think the code with the calculations would be the same.

Comment: Did you mean `total+=$7`? AND , what do you mean *"excluding "PATH" itself"*? You'll need to give us a reasonable value for `$dir`. If you launched your search with `dir=/usr`, then are you saying you don't want to count `/usr/bin` (as it is usually in the PATH)?  The only solution to that would be a "function" that converts the `PATH` value into a bunch of `sed` commands like `/\/usr\/bin/d` that is applied via a pipe in between the output of `find` and the input of `wc`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To count all subdirectories recursively under a directory, excluding the directory itself:

```
find "$d" -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

Example:

```
> mkdir -p 1; mkdir -p 2
> find . -type d | wc -l
3
> find . -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
2
```

---

Also do not parse the text output of `ls` command for any reason, see why [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

To print the byte count for all files (recursively) in the current directory:

```
find -type f -exec wc -c {} +
```

To get the total as a number alone (retract only the first field of last line)

```
find -type f -exec wc -c {} + | sed -n '$ s/ .*$//p'
```

or the same

```
find -type f -exec wc -c {} + | awk 'END{ print $1}'
```